# Ping high and internet slow when one computer is connected via wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a PC that, when connected to wifi, slows down the entire network but when it is connected to the router via cable it is perfectly fine. I have these images to illustrate. "PC1" is the PC in question. I ran a ping to the router on two different machines:

This is what it looked like from PC1 (the computer causing the issue -- you can see where I switched from cable to wifi (`"General failure"`) and back to cable `"Request timed out"`)):

[image]

This is what it looked like from another PC on the network:

[image]

What do you think could be causing this?

More info:

- It's a Linksys E2500 [image]
- I tried upgrading the firmware from 2.0 to 3.0 and I get an error ([image]) which I believe is due to the fact that you can't upgrade from 2.0  to 3.0 (https://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/E2500-firmware-update-failed/td-p/709187)?

EDIT:

- Adapter is Intel Dual-Band Wireless-AC 7265. Windows says the best driver is installed [image]
- Channel is both 2.4 and 5GHz : [image]

Comment: What Wi-Fi standard is the PC using? Is it transferring large amounts of data during the test?

Comment: 1) How can I find out what Wi-Fi standard it's using? 2) The only change is I switch Wi-Fi on and off. So unless there's something that prefers to run on Wi-Fi over a cable, IDK.

Comment: Sorry, I re-read your comments.  Wif on an e2500 should be slower but it shouldn't affect the rest of the network. How about trying DD-Wrt?

Comment: This is probably due to 802.11 Power Save.  Please see my answer in this previous post: https://superuser.com/questions/1316045/high-ping-in-lan-from-my-workstation-to-android/1316595#1316595

Comment: @pythonian no it's not power save. Because the problem is affecting all PCs on the network. You can see the ping goes high even on a separate PC.

Comment: @ryvantage - The wired machines have normal delay.  The wireless machines all have high delay.  So, yes... It's related to 802.11 (Wireless) power save :-) . You can turn power save off in the bowls of the adapter driver.

Comment: General Failure and Request Time Out is probably a packet drop when you switch from wireless to wired.

Comment: Please update the question with the wifi adapter make/model in question. Have you tried changing the channel your WiFi is operating on? Have you tried updating the drivers for said problematic adapter? It may just be a driver caveat, or a well known issue with the card, Regards.

Comment: Edits made, @Tim_Stewart

Comment: You most likely want the 2.4ghz on 1,6, or 11. If you have it on 9 you will get interference from 6 & 11 simultaneously if other routers in the area are on them. 36 & 48 are common defaults for 5.8ghz, try something higher in the band.

Comment: Give these drivers a shot, windows is a liar sometimes. https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27750/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-and-Drivers-for-Windows-10?product=83635

Answer (score 1):

I just solved similar issue. I downgraded Intel 7265 driver from version 19 to 18 and the issue is solved. Intel 7265 new driver works slow with some access point routers.