# Unstable latency - IOS / Android

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android

Editing for clarification!

I'm developing an extremely latency-critical application (Sub 45ms), whereby both server and client are on the same network, nothing is going over the internet.

Pinging a Desktop (Wired) or Laptop (Wireless) device from the Server it has a sub 5ms ping, as expected. However, when I ping a mobile device from the server, on the same network, the ping fluctuates substantially as below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQfKb.png

Same results on Samsung S10, Oppo 10X, Ipad Pro 2020, Oculus quest 2, various other headsets, basically any wireless mobile device.

I've ruled this out as a hardware problem, I have asked people to repeat the test on their local networks with the same results from everyone.

I did read about 802.11g compliance and also some fast wifi root override on android but I was wondering if anyone has experienced this or even has a solution to it?

Re:
[High ping in LAN from my workstation to Android](https://superuser.com/questions/1316045/high-ping-in-lan-from-my-workstation-to-android)

Comment: Your question is inconsistent - you talk about low latency on wireless & wired subnets but then mobile devices (which I assume means wireless), but then you talk about different networks.  In order to control latency you need SLA's and can't rely on 802.11* as its a free-for-all.   You should narrow down your problem using a variant of mtr and see where latency is coming in - most likely over the wifi hop (even on lan - phones tend to have smaller aerials).   What you are describing does sound to me like classic WIFI spectrum issues.

Comment: @davidgo Sorry re-reading the question it was worded rather poorly. The crux of the issue is that the latency only occurs on mobile devices (As you correctly assumed are wireless). On the same network, a wireless laptop has sub 5ms latency when pinging the server on the same network. I had others test on their local networks with the same issue, nothing is going over the internet in any of these tests. I'll modify the question to make it more clear!

Comment: You might also want to add the model of phones used.  While I suspect that the issue can be down to the vagaries of the 2.4 and 5 gig band and smaller antennas It could also be a CPU issue.  As it happens I just bought myself a new mid-range Android phone with snapdragon 732G chipset and I am getting consistent pings less then 3ms from it to my router.  (I live rurally, and am near my AP, so little Wifi noise - but it does show that phones can get low ping times out-the-box)

Comment: @davidgo No worries, added, it was a Samsung S10, Oppo 10x, Ipad Pro 2020 were all the devices. I have an S21 Ultra coming so I'll repeat the test on there, the latency is also only one way, i can ping the server from the phone without issue (3-5ms delay) its the Server to phone causing the issues!